# Measure Definition Equivalency

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given the definition of measurability of a set $F$:

$(1)$ A set $F \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is said to be *measurable* if for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ an open set $O$, containing $F$, such that $\mu^*(O - F) \leq \epsilon$.

Measurability is also defined as:

$(2)$ A set $F \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is said to be *measurable* if for every $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, with $\mu^*(A)<\infty $, the following is true
$$\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A \cap F)+\mu^*(A - F)$$

How does $(1) \implies (2)$?

$\mu^*$ denotes the *outer-measure* here

**LIMITATIONS:**

(1) The outer measure is defined as the infimum of the volume of cubes covering the set.

(2) Only an open set is the disjoint union of cubes (which provides for additivity).

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Is $\mu^*$ the outer-measure induced by the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Ramiro I am limited by the definitions I can use. (1) The outer measure is defined as the infimum of the volume of cubes covering the set. (2) Only an open set is the disjoint union of cubes (which provides for additivity). I can solve it if $A$ was open using the inequality of sums of volumes and the additivity property, but it is not given here. I know the key is to show that $\mu^*(A) \geq m^*(A \cap F)+\mu^*(A - F)$

Answer (score 0):

You can show using the definition of the outer measure that
$$\mu^*(A) = \inf \{ \mu^*(O) \mid A \subset O, \text{ $O$ open}\}.$$ According to your comment you are able to show that if $O$ is open and $F$ is measurable, then $$\mu^*(O \cap F) + \mu^*(O \setminus F) = \mu^*(O).$$ If $F$ is measurable and $A$ is arbitrary, you can let $O$ be an open set containing $A$ to find
$$\mu^*(A \cap F) + \mu^*(A \setminus F) \le \mu^*(O \cap F) + \mu^*(O \setminus F) = \mu^*(O).$$ Take the infimum over all such $O$ to obtain
$$\mu^*(A \cap F) + \mu^*(A \setminus F) \le \mu^*(A).$$

Comment: Thank you Umberto. I wish I had that definition of outer measure. Here we are relying on Stein's definition. $\mu^*(A) = inf \bigl\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |Q_j| \bigl\}$ with $A \subset \bigcup_j Q_j$

Comment: You can certainly use that. Do you know that $\mu^*(Q) = |Q|$ when $Q$ is a cube?

Comment: Yes, I do. So do I put $A$ in one "giant" cube $Q$ or do I use a collection of cubes?

Comment: Cover $A$ with cubes $\{Q_j\}$ and dilate them slightly to open cubes $\{Q_j'\}$. These cubes again form a cover of $A$ but their union is open. Call the union $O$. Then $$\mu^*(O) \le \sum \mu^*(Q_j') = \sum |Q_j'| \le (1+\epsilon) \sum |Q_j|.$$ Can you go from there?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I have however a question about this line in your proof. if $O$ is open and $F$ is measurable, then $$\mu^*(O \cap F) + \mu^*(O \setminus F) = \mu^*(O)$$ My thinking was to set $O$ as the disjoint union of cubes and take the sum of their intersections with $O$ and $O^c$. But is there a terse way to show this equality.